# How do collections and unlocks work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently found the collections tab in the cartel market and was surprised that there was a mega list of items that you can get from the cartel market.

About 2 years ago i bought a whole republic trooper set from the cartel market and i see now that i can 'unlock' it for other characters

the price is about half of what i paid, but if i unlock it on say my trooper, will it also be unlocked on my assassin then?

And if its unlocked and i want more copies, are these free or do they also require a fee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you bind an item to a character (by equipping, placing a bound mod into, or consuming/using it), it will be unlocked in Collections for that character.  That character can then redeem infinite copies of that item for free.

If you log onto another character on the same account, you can see all those items and choose to pay an additional fee to unlock an item account-wide (which also gives infinite free redemptions).  There's no way to just do the unlock for a single character via Collections; if you wanted to do that, you'd need to obtain a second unbound copy of the item and bind/use it on the desired character.

Note that some items cannot be redeemed from Collections even though they appear there.  Off the top of my head:

- Any unique items from Cartel Pack Reputation vendors
- Individual purple chest pieces containing mods
- Mod packs for your starship

Also, I should clarify that you need to bind an entire gear set on a single character for it to be unlocked in Collections.  Everything else is single-item.  After the Collections unlock, which you should see a mention in Chat about, it is safe to discard the unlocked items thanks to the infinite free redemptions (as long as they do not fall into the exceptions above).

Comment: What are some of the exceptions to the rule of infinite redemption?

Comment: @Vanguard66 If it's redeemable at all, it's infinitely redeemable (though some are pointless to redeem more than once, like Treek's mercenary contract).  The ones that aren't redeemable at all are listed above :)